# Do Array of items check on sql query using whereor and wherein Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a mysql query in which I need make a check for array of values in 2 columns using Or. **Inshort I have one array which needs to be checked on 2 columns using Or condition.**

## using sql

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE col_1 IN (1, 8, 3) 
OR
WHERE col_2 IN (1, 8, 3)
```

## using laravel

```
        $mu = DB::table('users')
        ->join('table_a', 'users.id', '=', 'table_a.user_id')
        ->select('table_a.user_id')
        //This are all AND
        ->where('table_b.search_status','available')
        ->where('table_b.role','<>',2)

        //This 2 parts needs to be in OR clause
        ->whereIn('table_b.lang',$seeks)
        ->whereIn('table_b.lang_2',$seeks)

        //This is AND too
        ->whereIn('table_a.language_id',$lang)
        ->get()->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
```

I want to do something like:

```
         ->where(function($q) 
        {
            $q->whereIn('table_b.lang',$seeks)
              ->orWhere(whereIn('table_b.lang_2',$seeks));
        })
```

But gives error: undefined $seeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure where condition to wrap them.

```
$mu = DB::table('users')
    ->join('table_a', 'users.id', '=', 'table_a.user_id')
    ->select('table_a.user_id')
    ->where('table_b.search_status', 'available')
    ->where('table_b.role','<>', 2)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($seeks) {
        $query->whereIn('table_b.lang', $seeks)
            ->orWhereIn('table_b.lang_2', $seeks);
    })
    ->whereIn('table_a.language_id', $lang)
    ->get()->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this:-

```
  ->where(function($q) use ($seeks)
    {
        $q->whereIn('table_b.lang',$seeks)
          ->orWhere(whereIn('table_b.lang_2',$seeks));
    });
```

Into

```
 ->where(function($q) use ($seeks)
    {
        $q->whereIn('table_b.lang',$seeks)
          ->orWhere(whereIn('table_b.lang_2',$seeks));
    });
```